# Clip Container inside CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter

i made this shape using CustumPainter Class , i want the container color to fill only the shape , like a full charged battery

[image]

this is how i made the shape

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();

    var path = Path();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 4.0;
    var posX;
    var posY;
    
    path.lineTo(size.width*0.75, 0);


    path.lineTo(size.width*0.75, size.height*0.25);

    path.lineTo(size.width*0.75, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.moveTo(size.width*0.75, size.height*0.25);
    path.lineTo(size.width*0.80, size.height*0.25);
    path.lineTo(size.width*0.80, size.height*0.75);
    path.lineTo(size.width*0.75, size.height*0.75);



    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
```

and this is my widget

```
return ClipRRect(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: CustomPaint(
          child: Container(
          ),
          painter: BatteryPainter(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another Path/rect inside Painter to handle fill color property , Also include `Paint()..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round` for better look on outer side.

, pass the value to control fill color.

```dart
class BatteryPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color fillColor;
  final double value;
  BatteryPainter({
    required this.value,
    this.fillColor = Colors.red,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    var path = Path();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 4.0;

    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, 0);

    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.25);

    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.25);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.80, size.height * 0.25);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.80, size.height * 0.75);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.75);

    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width * 0.75 * value, size.height);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawRect(
        rect,
        Paint()
          ..color = fillColor
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Use

```dart
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: BatteryPainter(value: value),
  ),
),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! its working like i want , but the little part in the front is not colored

Comment: The color is max limited up to `size.width * 0.75` as your paint width, you can include another rect if based on value or maybe doing combining two path

Answer (score 1):

To get a custom shape you must be using `clipPath` instead of clip Rect

```dart
ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomPath(),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 500,
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
```

More about [clipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)